# How to ensure ConfigurationManager points to correct App.config

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Recently created a new class library project and added a App.config file to it. App.config file contains DB connection string. But the current code

> ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionName"] gives me "null" .

But ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0] gives me result with name "LocalSqlServer" . But my App.config does not have any entry like this.

I don't see any other config files in my project . Then why this is happening ?

How could i ensure am pointing to correct App.Config?

Comment: Class libraries do not use their own App.config files - they use the config file (Web or App) of the application that is referencing the library.  Copy any relevant settings/entries from the library project's App.config to the config of the consuming application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App.Config` and other config files are read from the entry point of the program. Thus, if it is an application, the app.config file stored in the windows application project is read.

`LocalSqlServer` is the default SQL server when no other connection string is defined. This is the reason why it exists inside `ConnectionStrings` property.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the connection string to App.config of your main application, the executable. Alternatively,  if you want to define your own config file then make use of ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration Method.

More details in following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx